# SQL - Output header row, data and summarise data into footer row as string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've found variations of what I want, but not quite!

I need to export data to a specific string format where there's a header, the rows and the footer.

The problem that I'm having is in the footer, I need to have a sum of the records in the body.  Every example I've seen has fields and then summary as a field (i.e columns), whereas I have to have only 1 column output

Essentially what I want to appear is a table that looks like below (Please note - this is a bank requirement for data uploading.  I have no control over the format of the rows, I just need to know how I can summarise the data rows into the footer)

TIA

> ====Header Row Information=====
>
> Row 1
>
> Row 2
>
> Row 3
>
> Row 4
>
> ===Summary Information of above 4 rows  i.e sum of amount and count of rows===

***ETA SOME REAL-ISH DATA***

Thanks.  The output is essentially a list of transactions for EFT that goes to the bank (hence I didn't put much information in the data).

I'll have another go with dodgy data.  Note that in the code it is padded out and results to text to align columns.

> 0                 01WBC       Trust A/c          000000EFT0000-0000
>
> 0000-12349876543  500003456.62A & S Name                    123456            000-001 123456                  Our Law Trust00000000
> 0000-12341234567  500007654.56AM LastName                     654321            000-001 654321                  Our Law Trust00000000
> 0000-12348765432  500000315.35M Surname                        486245            000-001 957321                  Our Law Trust00000000
> 7999-9999            0011426.5300000000000011426.53                         3

(the trailer (starting with 7999) containing the total of the values (after 50) and the quantity of the number of records (3)

What I have so far.

```
SELECT
-----HEADER
'0' + space(17)                                                                         --RecordType (0)
+'01'
--Reel Sequence Number   ***If more than one processed, does this need to increase
+'WBC' + space(7)
--        Financial Institution
+(CAST(Trust' AS CHAR (26)))    --Name of User (provided)
+(CAST('000000' AS CHAR (6)))   --Number of user Supplying File (provided)
+(CAST('EFT0000-0000' AS CHAR (12)))    --Our Reference
    AS ROW1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  
    -----DATA
    '1'                               --RecordType
    +STUFF(ltrim(rtrim([DIRDEB_BSB])),4,0,'-')          --Bank/State/Branch Number
+ (CAST(ltrim(rtrim([DIRDEB_ACCNUM])) AS CHAR(9)))  --Account Number     (right justified and blank filled)
+' '                --Indicator (blank)
+ '50'               ---Transaction Code
+ right('0000000000' + convert(varchar,[amount]),10)    ---    Amount (right justified zero filled)
+(cast(ltrim(rtrim(DIRDEB_ACCNAME)) as char(32)))                ---Account     (left justified blank filled)
    + (CAST( right([MATTERID],6) AS CHAR(18)))   ---Lodgement Reference
     + (CAST( '000-001 123456'  AS CHAR(32)))   ---Trace Record  (BSB, Account, blank filled)
+ (CAST( 'Trust'  AS CHAR(16)))          --Name of Remitter (left and blank filled)
+ (CAST( '00000000'  AS CHAR(8)))       ---Amount of witholding tax zero filled
AS EFTEXPORT
  FROM AFF_EFT_Activity A
  where A.CHEQUEID NOT LIKE '%RV%' and A.CHEQUEID NOT LIKE '%CN%'  

  UNION ALL

 SELECT
   ----TRAILER
  '7'              --- Record Type (must be 7)
        +(CAST('999-999' AS CHAR (7)))    ---BSB Format Filler must be 999-999)
        +(CAST('' AS CHAR (12)))        ---Blank Filled
        --+(CAST(SUM(X.[amount]) as varchar(50)))       ---Net Total Amount
        +(CAST('0' AS CHAR (10)))                                                                       ---Credit Amount
        --+(CAST(SUM(X.[amount])  AS char (10)))        ---Debit amount
        +(CAST('' AS CHAR (24)))                    ---Blank
        +(CAST(count(*) AS CHAR (6)))           --- count of records
        +(CAST('' AS CHAR (40)))                    ---- Blank
        AS EFTSUMM
          FROM AFF_EFT_Activity X
          where X.CHEQUEID NOT LIKE '%RV%' and X.CHEQUEID NOT LIKE '%CN%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what you are trying to do.  Your example data doesn't really give any detail other than layout information.  Placing *real* data in your sample output would be very helpful.

In any case, here is a completely contrived example that shows how to create a dataset that looks similar to your sample:

```
declare @data table (name char(20), cost int, quantity int)

insert into @data values
('chair'   ,  75, 10),
('desk'    , 250,  4),
('monitor' , 120,  2),
('computer', 850,  1)

select 'ITEM                  COST  QNTY' as HeaderRow

union all

select replicate('-', 20) + '  ' + '----  ----' as HeaderLine

union all

select name + '  ' + cast(cost as char(4)) + '  ' + cast(quantity as char(4)) as Data
from   @data

union all

select replicate('-', 20) + '  ' + '----  ----' as FooterLine

union all

select 'Count: ' + cast(count(*) as char(5)) + replicate(' ', 8) + '  ' + cast(sum(cost) as char(4)) + '  ' + cast(sum(quantity) as char(4)) as FooterRow
from   @data
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
ITEM                  COST  QNTY
--------------------  ----  ----
chair                 75    10  
desk                  250   4   
monitor               120   2   
computer              850   1   
--------------------  ----  ----
Count: 4              1295  17
```

You could right align the numbers too, but that would take a bit more effort.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to respond.  Went on holidays (yay)
I've edited it as best I can to recreate what is required.  
It's called an ABA file and it's an import format for Australian Banks.  So I have no leg room to change what the output is - as hideous as it looks, when results are text it's in a column format with all the required padding.  Thanks.